# php: minimal string

Tags: php

how does the "tiny url" sites get so tiny ID url ?

i mean this : blabla.com/**JH7**

how can i get to such result? a functionality that is like md5 that does not repeat it self.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Over 8 million results, did you try google? https://www.google.com/#q=php+create+tinyurl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can simply iterate trough string:

```
php > $str = 'aaa';
php > $str++;
php > echo $str;
aab
```

The another option is to prepare function which will generate random strings containing of `a-zA-Z0-9` and than generate few millions of them into db (so you could just use them when needed) or do it in loop:

```
while( 1){
    $rand = randomString();
    if( isUnique( $rand)){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you , that's what i was looking for! but i got a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083311/php-mysql-instant-select-insert

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a database table with the columns `short_url` and `url`.
2. Start by inserting the record `a, example.com`.
3. Increment `short_url` with each new entry (`b`, `c`, ..., `a1` ...).

That's basically how these services work.

Comment: don't forget to use uppercase letters A-Z

Answer (score 1):

They use [base36 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36) to convert an integer to a compact string like that.

Using PHP:

```
<?php
$id     = 18367;
$base36 = base_convert($id, 10, 36); // convert to base36 "e67"
$base10 = base_convert($base36, 36, 10); // "e67" back to base 10, $id
```

As stated by deceze, base62 is also suitable which gives you a character set of a-zA-Z0-9 instead of just a-z0-9 like base36 does.

Comment: Probably more like base62 (upper/lower case)... :)

Comment: @deceze That would make more sense, I looked around but didn't see any tinyurl's with mixed case.  I think they went with 36 so there is no ambiguity between entering upper case vs lower case.  The wiki article says they use base36 but I don't know if that is still correct.